# Download and refresh data in background when app is running

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am looking a way, which should I follow to implement background download data. I mean if app is running (not in background mode) how to download data in a loop every 30 seconds? 
For standard download when `viewWillAppear` I am using Alamofire. 
Could someone show me the path to follow? What should I look for?

Comment: use Timer to call your API function after every X seconds and update your dataModel after each successful fetch.

Comment: @Apogee okay, thanks. But in which part of app should I use Timer?

Comment: @Apogee Okay, I was able to find it out. I've just put the timer in awakeFromNib, as it's collectionViewCell. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad I could help you.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is so simple, based on one of comment I've just put the timer

```
self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 30, target: self, selector: #selector(self.downloadData), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fetch logic in viewWillAppear. But if you want the data to be refreshed frequently, you can use timers to fetch the data. For fetching the data in background, you should enable background fetching under capabilities. You can init timers in a shared instance and then use that.